# Angular Imports and Modules / general question

Tags: angular

Its a general question about imports (TypeScript) an NgModule-Imports. For example, you need the ReactiveFormsModule in some of your own NgModules.

1. Do you need to import (TypeScript) it in every own xxx.component.ts?

I think yes, cause you need the TypeScript-Module to work with it.

2. Do you need to NgModule-Import it in every own xxx.module.ts?

I am not sure, cause sometimes I read "import it into your MainModule" ... But how can I pass it to the other NgModules?

Comment: Why you need additional Ng Modules ?

Comment: To divide my project into logical units. I am not sure about your question, do I use the term NgModule in the wrong context?

Comment: Have a look at LazyLoading modules. You application always load a module that stays always alive, and everything declared, imported or exported in that modulo will be available to all the other modules loaded at runtime in certain conditions (lazy loading). So, no, you don't need to import everything in every module. If you import ReactiveFromsModule in your main module it will be available anywhere else in your application, even in lazy loaded modules.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, it's not true, see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-snkwas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.module.ts) if you remove the ReactiveFormsModule in the exports in the "hello.module"

Comment: You put the ReactiveFormsModule in the hello.module, not in the app.module.

Answer (score 0):

When I built Angular project, I've just created few components & services in order to separate the project to units, but used **only a single @NgModule class**.

Then the imports / exports used in the main module were available in all child components, so was not needed to import / export them again.

Theoretically, I think you can create multiple modules, but it depends on your needs, for example, to create a separate module for routing.

Comment: if the project it's not very complex, your approach is correct, but in a medium-large application is better divide in modules

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules) (well, really in my opinion this explain is not very good)

The idea is, when you declare a component in a Module, this component only has access to the Directives/Components declares in this module and, if the module import anothers, the components declared in this modules. So yes, you need import ReactiveFormsModule in all the modules that declare components that use ReactiveFormsModule

Think in a Module as "something" that not know if it is imported or not.

Tipical you has a utilsModule with some components that use along your application, so futhermore that in declarations you put it exports:

```
    @NgModule({
      imports:[CommonModule] 
      declarations: [ ErrorComponent,ConfirmComponent],
      exports:[ErrorComponent,ConfirmComponent]
    })
    export class UtilModule { }
    }
```

And you has a module users that declare two components, and your component use ReactiveFormsModule

```
{
    @NgModule({
      imports:[CommonModule,ReactiveFormsModule,UtilsModule] 
      declarations: [ UserListComponent,UserEditComponent],
      //you not use export because UserListComponent and UserEditComponent 
      //are not use outside this module
    })
    export class UserModule { }
    }
```

In UserEditComponent you has, e.g.

```
import {FormGroup,FormControl} from '@angular/forms'
import {ErrorComponent} from '../utils/utils.module'
```